Probability of Specific Call Distribution Among Three Plumbers
Seems pretty simple, but can you check my solution please?
Consider a city with three plumbers, which we’ll call A, ﻿B, ﻿and C. ﻿One day, six residents of the city call a plumber. If each resident randomly selects a plumber from the phone directory, what is the probability that 3 ﻿residents call A, 2 ﻿call B, ﻿and 1 ﻿calls C?
$\textit{Solution}$:
Given that any of the residents can call any of the 3  plumbers, then the number of ways that it can happen is given by $O{R}^{6}_{3}=3^6=729$ (we can consider this as $|\Omega|$).
Then, the number of ways 3 residents can call plumber $A$ is $\binom{6}{3}=\frac{6!}{3!(6-3)!}=\frac{120}{6}=20$
For plumber $B$, there's 3 residents left not assigned to a plumber: $\binom{3}{2}=\frac{3!}{2!(3-2)!}=3$
And for the plumber $C$, there's only one resident left.
So, applying the fundamental principle of counting, we get that the number of ways that 3 residents can call plumber $A$, 2 residents can call plumber $B$ and one resident can call plumber $C$ is $\binom{6}{3}\times\binom{3}{2}=60$ and its probability is given by $60/729=0.0823$ or $8.23\%$.

Your solution looks good to me.

Equivalently, it follows from the multinomial distribution ($n=6,k=3,x_1=3,x_2=2,x_3=1$): $\frac{6!}{3!2!}(1/3)^6=\frac{60}{3^6}$.
